# SQL Access Error - Syntax error in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, append

What's wrong with SQL code below:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_HAMP_Actions ( Loan_ID, Action_ID, Event_User, Event_Time, Event_Station, Reason_ID )
VALUES(3238, 3, 'CONTROL', Now(), 'CONTROL', (SELECT tbl_Reasons.Reason_ID
FROM tbl_Reasons
WHERE tbl_Reasons.Reason = 'Incorrect Information'));
```

Comment: Please add any error messages that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use subqueries as values in Access.
Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_HAMP_Actions ( Loan_ID, Action_ID, Event_User, Event_Time, Event_Station, Reason_ID )
SELECT 3238, 3, 'CONTROL', Now(), 'CONTROL', Reason_ID
FROM tbl_Reasons
WHERE tbl_Reasons.Reason = 'Incorrect Information'
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) Please check answer as accepted if solution was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    (SELECT tbl_Reasons.Reason_ID
FROM tbl_Reasons
WHERE tbl_Reasons.Reason = 'Incorrect Information')
```

could this part of the code return more than one row? If so then this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have better luck with a query that looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_HAMP_Actions 
    (
        Loan_ID, 
        Action_ID, 
        Event_User, 
        Event_Time, 
        Event_Station, 
        Reason_ID 
    ) VALUES (
        3238, 
        3, 
        'CONTROL', 
        Now(), 
        'CONTROL', 
        DLookup("Reason_ID","tbl_Reasons","Reason = 'Incorrect Information'")
    )
```